# Publicly available but privately owned

Tags: terminology, business-language, legalese

I'm struggling to find correct terminology to refer to something which is freely available (as in, no monetary cost) but is likely not free from copyright. Everyone may use a newspaper article that is online and doesn't require a subscription to view, but that doesn't mean that it is an example of "Open Data".

"Public domain"? I'm pretty sure that's not right, it's privately owned, after all.

Comment: If you're asking for a particular phrase like "public domain" to refer to what you describe I'm not sure what it is. 
However, there are a series of "creative commons" licenses that cater for levels of coypright down to free use in the public domain. See https://creativecommons.org/licenses/.

Comment: @remnant oh absolutely. Something like wikipedia would be like that, but abstracts of journal papers, newspaper articles, or twitter tweets would all be examples of things that anybody can read but might be illegal (technically) to use (reproduce) without permission from the author or owner

Comment: Perhaps 'open access' rather than 'open data'. Though I've a niggling feeling that may have some other accepted usage. edited to add. It seems to specifically refer to 'research papers' but otherwise same definition as you have for access https://www.theguardian.com/higher-education-network/blog/2014/oct/27/-sp-whats-the-biggest-challenge-facing-open-access

Comment: How about **uncharged**? This implies that ownership is retained by the producer of the work but that they have chosen to offer it freely over a given medium. It also implies that they can withdraw uncharged access at any time, charge for it over another medium and enforce their ownership rights in cases of plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'publicly accessible' - data, writing, journals etc. This does not state explicitly that it is 'under copyright' but I'm not sure why you would need to state that anyway. Aren't all or most kinds of written articles naturally under the copyright of the author? So won't people just expect that anyway? And if not, the 'Creative Commons' licencing would be the kind of alternate licencing that you might want to mention it might be under, as a commenter noted.

Comment: Please, *publicly,* not *publically.* The root is *public,* not *publical.* However, you are right; everything is copyright (even if that right is not enforced) until it enters the public domain.

Answer (score -1):

"Freeware" would mean exactly that, although its usage out of a software context might be a bit strange.